# How to toggle password show and hide using useReducer in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-reducer

[https://codesandbox.io/s/loginusingreducer-fo3bgv?file=/src/App.js](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Hi,
I am having 2 issues in this application. First one is when I am trying to show/hide the password using useReducer. When I chick on the show icon ,I can see the password but cannot toggle it.

The second issue is when I click on the login button, I don't see "Logging In" text which is supposed to show if isLoading is true and I already have set that condition. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

I have tried this on code sandbox. Here is the link to it
[https://codesandbox.io/s/loginusingreducer-fo3bgv?file=/src/App.js](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I tasted it it's working fine

Comment: I don't know why it behaved like that. I closed it and opened it again and now everything looks fine. Thanks!